# JDBI using Inner Classes

Tags: java, reflection, jdbi

I have a POJO that contains an inner (non-static) class as it shared the parents id

```
public Long getId() {
   return Parent.this.getId();
}
```

Now I am trying to map these in JDBI but it appears that JDBI cannot instaniate the inner class?

```
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.xxxx.Parent$Child
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.FieldMapper.construct(FieldMapper.java:214)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xxxx.Parent$Child.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 39 more
```

My experience with inner classes is sadly lacking - what am I missing here?  Or is this simply a deficiency in the JDBI library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-static inner class can only be constructed in reference to an instance of the outer class.  So for example consider the class:

```
public class Outer {

    class Inner {}

    void implicitReferenceToThis() {
        new Inner();
    }

    void explicitReferenceToThis() {
        this.new Inner();
    }

    static void noReferenceToOuter() {
        // new Inner(); // doesnt compile
    }

    static void explictReferenceToOuter() {
        new Outer().new Inner();
    }
}
```

While in the first method it looks like there is a no-args constructor for Inner it is actually implicitly referencing *this*.  You can see this because you can't use the same code in the the third (static) method.

Indeed the syntax may look a little odd, but the second and fourth method demonstrate how to call the constructor on an explicit object.

How this relates to you question the comes to the stack trace.

```
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
```

It looks like that the code is trying to instantiate *Outer$Inner* with *newInstance()* which can't work because there is no reference to an instance of *Outer*.

I'm not sure I would expect a reflective mapper to handle inner classes out of the box so I wouldn't say that it was a deficiency in JDBI, but you may need to do some wrangling with a custom mapper or extend a reflective mapper to get this to work for you.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking - and writing a custom mapper defeats the purpose of wanting to use JDBI for it's Bean/FieldMappers anyway.  Guess I'll just pull them out as standalone classes - not that big a deal, just trying to be tricky :)

Answer (score 0):

It attempts to create an instance of your class Child, but this class has no default constructor (constructor without any parameters).